# Implement new IdentityServer in .NetCore MVC with existing UserDb

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I would like to create a new IdentityServer4 for a .NetCore MVC Project without ASP-Authentication, which gets the users from an existing MS SQL-database.

The user database should not have to be changed, if not necessary.

Unfortunately, previous tutorials could not help me, because a lot has been revised.

What steps are necessary to achieve this?

Hope you can help me,

best regards

Answer (score 1):

The Identity server i am currently working on used to connect to a MsSQL server database that contained legacy users.   The identity server itself stored its own tables in its database.   I believe the way it worked was it had its on UserDbContext added to the middelwere.

So what we had was.

- Identity server database - clients and stuff
- Legacy user database -  All user data.

Which is close to what you are talking about

```
services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(settingsSetup.ConnectionStrings.UserDatabaseConnection));
```

Everything ran though a custom UserManager.

It no longer runs this way as over the summer i integrated all of the users to Asp .net core identity and the data now resides in the same database as the identity server.

I can dig around in the solution control old branches if you need more info.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I am a beginner  in IdentityServer,
I am grateful for any info I can get. kind regards